# Maven assembly plugin zips the jar.original content and not the executable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-lifecycle

How to pack the **executable jar** in zip using maven-assembly-plugin and not the Original file i.e. **.jar.original**

Currently, on providing maven-assembly-plugin as dependency, it packs the jar.original in the zip.

***maven-assembly-plugin*** definition

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>

                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

***assembly.xml***

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>assembly-id</id>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
                <include>**/RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</include>
            </includes>
            
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

Here, RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, is the jar I want in the zip. However, it takes content of RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original as RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and zips that.

**pom.xml*** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hsbc.gmmo.frtb</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestCoordinator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestCoordinator</name>
    <description>Rest API to talk to FDS/Vault system</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <aws.version>1.11.818</aws.version>
        <org.json.version>20200518</org.json.version>
        <swagger.version>3.0.0</swagger.version>
        <lz4.version>1.7.0</lz4.version>
        <opencsv.version>5.0</opencsv.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lz4</groupId>
            <artifactId>lz4-java</artifactId>
            <version>${lz4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> -->
                    <!-- <exclude>trustedterms/**</exclude> -->
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>dsnexus</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.hsbc:8081/nexus</nexusUrl>
                    <!--<stagingProfileId>ff935ee1cf3eb</stagingProfileId> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>

                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
                    <!-- <mainClass></mainClass> <layout>ZIP</layout> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>dsnexus</id>
            <url>https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.hsbc:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases
            </url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>dsnexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.hsbc:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
            </url>
        </snapshotRepository>

    </distributionManagement>


</project>
```

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to package? Where is the `RestCoordinator` coming from?

Comment: SpringBoot application , it is the name of my project. 

Also in POM,

Comment: Also in POM,<groupId>com.hsbc.gmmo.frtb</groupId>
 <artifactId>RestCoordinator</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>RestCoordinator</name>

Comment: I'd guess that the assembly plugin simply runs *before* the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. From what you provided it's not possible to tell certainly however.

Comment: Please show the full pom where the maven-assembly-plugin is defined ...

Comment: @slauth From the console log, it shows that order as -> maven-compiler-plugin --> maven-assembly-plugin --> maven-spring-boot-plugin

In the target folder, two artefacts are created :
1. RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original (1.5mb)
2. RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (42mb executable jar file)

Maven assembly zips taking contents of the jar.original file and not the executable jar file.

Comment: @khmarbaise added pom code above

Comment: So based on that I simply don't understand why you need maven-assembly-plugin. A spring boot needs to be packed by spring-boot-maven-plugin (boot etc.) Apart from that move the maven-assembly-plugin after the spring boot maven plugin in the pom file... because while two plugins are bound to the same life cycle phase there order of execution is given by the order in the pom file...

Comment: Got it, this scenario worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is running after the `maven-assembly-plugin`. So at the time the assembly is created, there simply is no executable JAR file available yet. To fix the execution order just move the definition of the `maven-assembly-plugin` below the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in your POM.